# Keep pulling division to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have my HTML structure as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

and Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".container").click(function() {
        $(".menu").css("left", "+=50px");
    });
});
```

finally CSS:

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  width:auto;
  background:lightgray;
}

.menu{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:35px;
  background-color:green;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  transition: left 1s;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85QCk/) of the above code.

My aim is to pull the `.menu` div to the left, sort of gravity, but to the left. But on click the div should move to the right.
It has to be like how flappy bird works, but sideways.

Comment: do you want the animation to stop when it hits left 0 ? or can it go past the left side of the screen?

Comment: Yes, animation has to stop once `left==0`

Comment: How does the title of your question related to the problem?

Comment: I thought of the title because I thought that a function could be run, say `gravity()`, which will keep pulling the object to the left. I guess it doesn't make much sense now that I see it, I will work on better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `animate callback` function for position back to the right,

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    $(".menu").stop().animate({left : "+=50px"},1000,function(){
        $(".menu").animate({ left : "0" },1000);
    });
});
```

and remove `transition` from your `css`.

check this fiddle for this..http://jsfiddle.net/85QCk/14/

Comment: what about this one http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/85QCk/17/ , it will provide constant speed

Comment: @Arjun That's what I'm talking about! I think it'll do the trick for now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You have to call `e.stopPropagation();` to stop the click event in the `container`'s children or the `menu` in our case from propagating up and triggering the click event on the `container` or the parent.

```
var menuOpen = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".container").click(function () {
        if (!menuOpen) {
            $(".menu").css("left", "+=50px");
            menuOpen = true;
        }
    });

    $(".menu").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (menuOpen) {
            $(".menu").css("left", "-=50px");
            menuOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQH7e/1/) example of the code in action.

Comment: No, what @Arjun did here: http://jsfiddle.net/85QCk/14/ is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Okay, glad you found a solution for your problem.